# Calculate the percentage and store in a csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have following df.

```
    PredictedFeature    counts_x        counts_y        counts
0   100                   1837            1224            850
1   200                    215             60              2
2   3600                   172             14             147
3   4600                   143             124            138
4   162                    30              16              20
```

Now, Here I want to calculate the percentage of each feature with respect to `counts_y`

SO, the formula will be like ,

```
  1.  (100/counts_y) * counts_x

  2.    (100/counts_y) * counts
```

Wnat to have a final dataframe like

```
predictedfeature   counts_per      counts_x
   100                90             20
```

kind of output.

Kindly help me with this ?

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
df["counts_x"] = df["counts_x"] * 100 / df["counts_y"]

df["counts_per"] = df["counts"] * 100/ df["counts_y"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the computation of the percentage is pretty simple. Just create two additional columns which store the computed results.

```
countdata["counts_x"] = countdata["counts_x"] * 100 / countdata["counts_y"]

countdata["counts_per"] = countdata["counts"] * 100/ countdata["counts_y"]
```

Now, your dataframe has two more columns. If you don't require the already existing columns in your dataframe, just drop them. Otherwise, to write only the new columns to a csv, do the following:

```
cols = ["PredictedFeature", "counts_per", "counts_x"]
countdata.to_csv('data.csv', columns = cols)
```

Basically, you are choosing the columns which you want to write to your csv.